# How does 25% CO2/75% Ar welding gas exist?

Tags: physical-chemistry

What state does a 25% $\ce{CO2}$ / 75% $\ce{Ar}$ mixture exist in under high pressure? This mixture is a common welding shielding gas. I'm not sure if manufacturers are referring to this mixture by partial pressures or by mass, though I would think partial pressures. For both cases, I calculated the partial pressures of the gasses in the mix. In both cases, the $\ce{CO2}$ is in the gas state (34-35 bar) and the $\ce{Ar}$ is in the supercritical phase (around 110 bar). I don't really understand supercritical fluids, though.

**So what state does this mixture exist in? Do supercritical fluids mix with gases the same way two regular gases would? How does this mixture behave inside the bottle?**

For the record, here are the numbers I arrived at:

Calculation Conditions:

| Condition | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Volume | 0.1 m<sup>3</sup> |
| Total Pressure | 2100 psia / 14479 kPa |
| Temperature | 293 K |
| $\ce{CO2}$ gas constant | [0.1889 kJ/kg$\cdot$K](https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/property_tables/gas/idealGas.html) |
| $\ce{Ar}$ gas constant | [0.2081 kJ/kg$\cdot$K](https://www.ohio.edu/mechanical/thermo/property_tables/gas/idealGas.html) |

If by pressure, it's easy:

| Gas | Partial Pressure |
| --- | --- |
| $\ce{CO2}$ | 3619.7 kPa |
| $\ce{Ar}$ | 10859.2 kPa |

If by mass, it's a little more involved. I calculate the pressure per mass in kPa/kg using

$$
\frac{P}{m} = \frac{RT}{V}
$$

| Gas | Pressure per Mass |
| --- | --- |
| $\ce{CO2}$ | 553.48 kPa/kg |
| $\ce{Ar}$ | 609.73 kPa/kg |

The total pressure has to equal 14479 kPa. So the total pressure is given by

$$
P_T = \left(\frac{P}{m}_\ce{CO2}\right) m_\ce{CO2} + \left(\frac{P}{m}_\ce{Ar}\right) \left(\frac{\%Ar}{\%CO2}\right)m_\ce{CO2}
$$

Solving for $m_\ce{CO2}$ gives

$$
m_\ce{CO2} = \frac{P_T}{\left(\frac{P}{m}_\ce{CO2}\right) + \left(\frac{P}{m}_\ce{Ar}\right) \left(\frac{\%Ar}{\%CO2}\right)} = \pu{6.077 kg}
$$

Thus the Argon mass would be 18.230 kg.

The ideal gas law gives the pressures for these gas masses:

| Gas | Pressure |
| --- | --- |
| $\ce{CO2}$ | 3363.4 kPa |
| $\ce{Ar}$ | 11115.6 kPa |

[image: Argon Phase Diagram]

Comment: The gas is sold by molecule percentage. Seems unlikely there is a good thermodynamic reason for the delivered gas to deviate from that percentage.

Comment: @JonCuster so that would be equivalent to partial pressure, then. Does a mixture of a supercritical fluid and a normal gas act like a gas practically?

Comment: short answer: yes it does. ;)

Comment: As long as there is no first order phase transition there is no issue. And going from a supercritical fluid to a 'normal' gas around the critical point is not a first order phase transition.